# How to proper add xml namespace in an xmlstarlet update command when along used with XPath

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

What is wrong with my xmlstarlet command?
I am trying to update the version element of my pom.xml if the following constraints are true under parent element
groupId == com.cisco.aems
and
version == 3.700.11-SNAPSHOT

the xml namespace concept is complicating my understanding of xmlstarlet syntax, any help on fixing my xmlstarlet problem will be appreciated.
Thank you :-)

I have tried variations of the below command

```
xmlstarlet ed -N a="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -u "/a:groupId[.='com.cisco.aems' and following
-sibling::version[1] = '3.700.11-SNAPSHOT']/a:following-sibling::version[1]" -x "concat(.,'-done')" pom_sandbox_nam.xml
```

either I get a Invalid expression error or nothing but I don't the expected result

Sample pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>avc-utils</artifactId>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.cisco.aems</groupId>
    <artifactId>aems_parent_pom</artifactId>
    <version>3.700.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
</project>
```

Expected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>avc-utils</artifactId>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.cisco.aems</groupId>
    <artifactId>aems_parent_pom</artifactId>
    <version>3.700.11-SNAPSHOT-done</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
</project>
```

Actual Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>avc-utils</artifactId>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.cisco.aems</groupId>
    <artifactId>aems_parent_pom</artifactId>
    <version>3.700.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
xmlstarlet ed -N a="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -u "/a:project/a:parent/a:groupId[.='com.cisco.aems' and following-sibling::a:version[1] = '3.700.11-SNAPSHOT']/following-sibling::a:version[1]" -x "concat(.,'-done')" pom_sandbox_nam.xml
```

It results in the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>avc-utils</artifactId>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.cisco.aems</groupId>
    <artifactId>aems_parent_pom</artifactId>
    <version>3.700.11-SNAPSHOT-done</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
</project>
```

You missed to specify the whole path to the element you wanted to change and not to specify the appropriate namespace.

Comment: What if what Im missing is xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ?

Comment: I do not know if that's supported by XMLStarlet. But you can always use an XSLT template with e.g. `xsltproc`.